# How to get the number of category labels displayed vs. hidden

Tags: highcharts, label, categories

I have a column range chart with a set of text category labels - I am trying to figure out how I can determine the maximum number of categories and values to display without Highcharts automatically hiding some category labels because there is not enough room to display them.  In other words, I don't want to see a chart with 40 values but only 32 category labels visible.  How can I get the actual number of displayed labels programmatically so I can reduce my data set to that number of values?

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? See: http://jsfiddle.net/cfad2vvL/1/ - when there isn't enough space for categories, these are displayed in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tickPositions` on the `Axis` you want:

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ...]
}
```

This will tell the chart which points to show as labels: http://jsfiddle.net/cfad2vvL/

There is also `tickPositioner` which takes a `function` and you can do whatever you want with the labels.